# Send richtextbox Text to Listview

Tags: c#, listview, richtextbox

I want to send my richtextbox data to listview line by line. Note: My richtextbox data is updating with coming data from anywhere.

If I use ;

```
item.SubItems.Add(richTextBox1.Text);
```

It will be;

```
richTextBox1data     Listview
Data                 ID   Data
1001                 1    100110021003...
1002                 2  
1003                 3  
.                    4
.                    .
.                    .
```

If I use ;

```
   for()
   {
    item.SubItems.Add(richTextBox1.Lines[j].ToString()); 
   }
```

It will be;

```
richTextBox1data     Listview
Data                 ID   Data
1001                 1    1001
1002                 2    10011002
1003                 3    1000110021003
.                    4    .........
.                    .    ..........
.                    .
```

I try to do like below

```
richTextBox1data     Listview
Data                 ID   Data
1001                 1    1001
1002                 2    1002
1003                 3    1003
.                    4    .
.                    .    .
.                    .    .
```

Comment: Can I solve  my problem with using  item.SubItems.Add(richTextBox1.Line[i]) ?

Comment: Why dont you try and see whats happens?

Comment: it does not works. Just because I made it with for() and it should be like  listView1.Items[1].SubItems[i+1].Add something like that which is not supported by visual studio or I could not find it. Regards

Comment: Why you not trying what you wrote first? Of course it is not supported what you think it should be. If you read documentation you can find that [SubItems.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7x34tef(v=vs.110).aspx) adds item to collection and with [SubItems\[i\]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybas8bcb(v=vs.110).aspx) you can access appropriate item.

Comment: What about splitting the text beforehand?
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: Answers are OK for what i asked, but the problem is I forget the saying my richtextbox1 is updating with coming data. The output is like; 0 data0 /0 data0 1 data1 /0 data0 1 data1 2 data2 /..... I think it is better changing richTextBox1.Lines.Length which causes problem which is writing previous data always. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
foreach (string input in rchTest.Lines)
{
    item.SubItems.Add(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
   lvi.SubItems.Add(richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
   listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

provided of course the `Listview` is in `Detail` mode and has two `Columns`

Comment: Dear TaW, your codes are OK for data transfer richbox to listview (with gridline). But If richtextbox is updating as my richtextbox. It will cause a problem like (output): 0 data0 /0 data0 1 data1 /0 data0 1 data1 2 data2 /..... How can I solve it. Thank you for shring time.

Comment: How and when is your RTB updated? you may wan to insert a `listView1.Items.Clear();` before copying the data into the ListView..